# Python: How should I loop my function correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, macos

I'm coding a script in Python that is supposed to scrape a website and if it finds a keyword it should post a text on Twitter. I would like this script to scrape the website once a minute. Everything is working fine except the looping.

The function that scrapes, identifies keywords and posts is called "checksite".

It looks like this:

```
def checksite():
    try:
        if any(c in latest2 for c in companies) and not any(c in latest2 for c in dont_post):
        api.update_status(twitter_post)
        print("a tweet has been shared")
        requests.post(web_hook_url,data=json.dumps(slack_msg))
        sleep(60)

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print("Already tweeted")
        sleep(60)

    except StopIteration as e:
        print("No keyword")
        sleep(60)


while True:
    checksite()
```

I want the code to loop and check the site once a minute despite the outcome of the checksite-function. I tried using the while True for this. I've been writing all the code in Sublime Text. What am I doing wrong?

Thankful for help!

Answer (score 0):

On `checksite`, catch the exception raised into `try` with a `except` block, and that's all.

EDIT:
In fact, i just noticed that you already catch some exceptions, i've been induced in error by the bad indentation.
You currently catching some exceptions ... but you should also have a catchall block if others exceptions are raised.

EDIT 2: 
What is the problem with current code? Error ? Misbehaviour? please, more details.

Comment: I don't understand how you mean. Could you please try to explain? 
EDIT: Currently everything works as it should if i just run "checksite()" but when I place it in "while True:" nothing at all happens. It says "Building" for a couple of seconds in Sublime Text but then it goes away and nothing happens.

Comment: Enrich your question with details please... What is the problem ?

Comment: Please see comment above.